# What is the fastest moving macroscopic object people have made?

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

The Parker Solar Probe will move at 690,000 km/h (430,000 mph), or 0.064% the speed of light, at its closest approaches to the sun.  [Parker Solar Probe top speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423100/parker-solar-probe-top-speed)

Will that be the highest speed yet achieved by a manufactured, visible-size object?  If not, what is?

I have tagged this question assuming the highest speed will by something we send to space -- but I do not know that.  It could as well be some kind of thing I have not thought of at all.m

Comment: The exhaust velocity of the ion thruster can reach 210 km / s.

Comment: @AlexTrounev but that wouldn't qualify as a "visible-sized object". The best it could be seen as is a trail similar to a comet tail, but not a fast-moving object.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about current engineering achievements, not physics.

Comment: @Ruslan The exhaust velocity of the ion thruster is similar to the Parker Solar Probe speed :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(speed)) Wikipedia page, the current fastest macroscopic man-made object was a shell (mass about 0.1 mg) in an inertial confinement fusion capsule driven by the National Ignition Facility. This particle was measured to be travelling at a speed of $445000\text{m/s}$ or $0.0015c$.