# Analytical expressions for acceleration due to zonal harmonics of a gravitational field?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential, centrifugal-force, spherical-harmonics

Wikipedia's [Geopotential_model; The deviations of Earth's gravitational field from that of a homogeneous sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential_model#The_deviations_of_Earth.27s_gravitational_field_from_that_of_a_homogeneous_sphere) discusses the expansion of the potential in spherical harmonics. The first few *zonal harmonics* ($\theta$ dependence only) are seen after the monopole term in

$$u = -\frac{GM}{r} - \sum_{n=2} J^0_n \frac{P^0_n(\sin \theta)}{r^{n+1}}$$

where $P^0_n$ are [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). I want to calculate the first three terms for $J_2, J_3, J_4$ by hand. I have

$$P^0_2(\sin \theta) = \frac{1}{2}(3 \sin^2 \theta - 1)$$

$$P^0_3(\sin \theta) = \frac{1}{2}(5 \sin^3 \theta - 3 \sin \theta)$$

$$P^0_4(\sin \theta) = \frac{1}{8}(35 \sin^4 \theta - 30 \sin^2 \theta + 3)$$

Since these terms are cylindrically symmetric I can write

$$\sin^2(\theta) = \frac{x^2+y^2}{r^2} = \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} $$

**The $J_2$ term** in the potential is then:

$$u_{J_2} = -J_2 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{r^3} \frac{3x^2 + 3y^2 - r^2}{r^2} = -J_2 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{r^5} (2x^2 + 2y^2 - z^2)$$

and the acceleration from this would be the negative gradient $-\nabla u$ or

$$\mathbf{a_{J_2}} = -\nabla u_{J_2}$$

Using [this Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-del%28%28-1%2F2%29%282x%5E2%2B2y%5E2-z%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E%285%2F2%29%29) to make sure I don't make errors taking derivatives, I get (after a slight adjustment)

$$a_x = J_2 \frac{x}{r^7} \left( \frac{9}{2} z^2 - 3(x^2 + y^2) \right)$$

$$a_y = J_2 \frac{y}{r^7} \left( \frac{9}{2} z^2 - 3(x^2 + y^2)\right)$$

$$a_z = J_2 \frac{z}{r^7} \left( \frac{3}{2}z^2 - 6 (x^2 + y^2)\right)$$

and **these look very similar to** but not the same as the results in Wikipedia's [Geopotential_model; The deviations of Earth's gravitational field from that of a homogeneous sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential_model#The_deviations_of_Earth.27s_gravitational_field_from_that_of_a_homogeneous_sphere):

$$a_x = J_2 \frac{x}{r^7} \left(6 z^2 - \frac{3}{2}(x^2 + y^2\right)$$

$$a_y = J_2 \frac{y}{r^7} \left(6 z^2 - \frac{3}{2}(x^2 + y^2\right)$$

$$a_z = J_2 \frac{z}{r^7} \left(3 z^2 - \frac{9}{2}(x^2 + y^2\right)$$

I'm close but I can't reproduce Wikipedia's result here. Once I'm confident with the process I can continue for the $J_3$ and $J_4$ terms and start doing numerical integration of orbits.

Comment: different but related: [What is the sign of Earth's J2?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43394/12102)

Comment: Note that the Wikepedia article is using spherical coordinates $\theta=0$ is at the equator rather than the pole. I.e. we have $\cos^2\theta = \frac{x^2+y^2}{r^2}$

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8074/2451

Comment: @mmeent I have a hunch that's going to be exactly what's necessary, and I'll verify as soon as morning coffee kicks in, thanks! Assuming it does I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Qmechanic I considered then rejected the [`newtonian gravity`](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-gravity) tag because it's wiki excerpt is "The Newtonian model of gravity in which the force between two objects is given by GMm/r^2." shild my question is only about the higher harmonics which this explicitly excludes. Yes Newton did address Earth's oblateness at some point, but I don't think this tag applies based on its wiki.

Comment: The underlying interaction is still Newtonian gravity. If you feel you can improve the tag wiki please do.

Comment: @Qmechanic  oh I see what you mean, yes the potential is just the integral of $-\rho/r$; there's [none of this going on](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457417/83380) (currently unanswered).

Comment: @mmeent Thank you for your suggestion! I've posted a partial answer; I'm almost there, but I haven't been able to get rid of a minus sign between my results for acceleration and those in Wikipedia, which still harkens back to [What is the sign of Earth's J2?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43394/12102)

Comment: The signs in your first equation, differ from those in eq (9) on the linked Wikipedia page.

Comment: @mmeent if there is an equation-specific form of reading disability, then I've had it my whole life. I've looked at that several times and each time I've seen minus signs in front of all terms, apparently because my brain *thinks there should be* and overwrites what my eyes are providing. *Thank you very much for your patience and kind help!*

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at [@mmeent's comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/547131/analytical-expressions-for-acceleration-due-to-zonal-harmonics-of-a-gravitationa#comment1236450_547131) suggesting that the spherical coordinates used in the [linked Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential_model#The_deviations_of_Earth.27s_gravitational_field_from_that_of_a_homogeneous_sphere) set the polar angle equal to zero at the equator rather than the pole.

> where [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (r, θ, φ) are used, given here in terms of cartesian (x, y, z) for reference

While that link shows $\theta = 0$ at the "north pole" (how I've usually seen spherical coordinates defined) the equations directly below that line do indeed define $\theta = 0$ to be the equator with $z=0$:

$$x = r \cos \theta \cos \phi$$

$$y = r \cos \theta \sin \phi$$

$$x = r \sin \theta$$

$$\sin^2(\theta) = \frac{z^2}{r^2} = \frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} $$

then ([noting that in the original question I'd put a minus sign where none existed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/547131/analytical-expressions-for-acceleration-due-to-zonal-harmonics-of-a-gravitationa?noredirect=1#comment1237021_547131)):

$$u_{J_2} = +J_2 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{r^3} \frac{3z^2 - r^2}{r^2} = J_2 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{r^5} (2z^2 - (x^2 + y^2))$$

and using $\mathbf{a_{J_2}} = -\nabla u_{J_2}$ and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-del%28%28-1%2F2%29%282z%5E2-%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E%285%2F2%29%29) I get:

$$a_x = J_2 \frac{x}{r^7} \left( 6 z^2 - \frac{3}{2}(x^2 + y^2) \right)$$

$$a_y = J_2 \frac{y}{r^7} \left( 6 z^2 - \frac{3}{2}(x^2 + y^2) \right)$$

$$a_z = J_2 \frac{z}{r^7} \left( 3 z^2 - \frac{9}{2}(x^2 + y^2) \right)$$

which agrees with Wikipedia.

Comment: I'll add $J_3$ and $J_4$ in the morning.

Comment: oops, I didn't say *which* morning... I'll get to it eventually.